# Name for series with subtracted base

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, signal-processing

I'm looking for a standard name in the math world for a sequence, which has some base subtracted, where the base is close to the average. There is an example:

Assume there is a sequence with the first ten elements: `9, 7, 4, 0, 5, 7, 3, 0, 8, 1, ...`.  The average of the first five `5  9, 7, 4, 0, 5` is `5`. Let's name this the base since all these and other numbers, appearing in the sequence are about five, and this value will not be changed further.
The source sequence with the base subtracted is `4,  2, -1, -5,  0,  2, -2, -5,  3, -4, ...`

Whether there is a standard coined name for this conversion, like *centered sequence *, *sequence off by approximate mean* or anything else?

Comment: The word *offset* rather than "off" would be better.  You could also use the words *translated* or *shifted* to describe the new "series" derived from the old one.  Also *sample* would be better than "series" if the entries are derived from a random choice, as "series" will in some contexts imply that the values are to be summed.

Comment: If you subtracted the average of all the terms the average in the new sequence would be $0$. There might be a name for that. I doubt there is one for your example. If you need a construction like this often then you should define it carefully and name it appropriately. If you [edit] the question to show us why you need this we might be able to help.

Comment: This is a method often used in DSP and image processing to increase the calculation numeric stability. Let's say there are terabytes of data with a range from `20000` to `30000`, it's better to calculate it shifted to zero, based on the first data sample to a range `-5000` to `5000`.